# I'm trying to add multiple camera switches to a vehicle in Unity and I am not sure how to code it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My project is from the "Create with Unity" tutorial unit 1 with a simple vehicle moving down a road. I originally had 1 camera which worked, but when I changed the code to work with multiple cameras I couldn't get the compiler to work.

The 3 cameras are supposed to display different angles of the tank while controlling the vehicle. I assume something is wrong with how I wrote the FollowPlayer.cs "void LateUpdate()" method, but I don't know how to make it work. It all went wrong when I changedthe FollowPlayer class from 1 cam to 3 cams.

The picture shows the unity visuals and all relevant class coding is below.
I'm new to unity and c#, so any help would be appreciated!

[image: Unity Project Visuals]

***MY CAM SWITCH CLASS***

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CamSwitch : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject cam1;
    public GameObject cam2;
    public GameObject cam3;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Switch1"))
        {
            cam1.SetActive(true);
            cam2.SetActive(false);
            cam3.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Switch2"))
        {
            cam1.SetActive(false);
            cam2.SetActive(true);
            cam3.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Switch3"))
        {
            cam1.SetActive(false);
            cam2.SetActive(false);
            cam3.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

***THE CLASS I THINK I MESSED UP***

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public Vector3 offset1= new Vector3(0, 5, -7);
    public Vector3 offset2 = new Vector3(0, 3.83, -7);
    public Vector3 offset3 = new Vector3(0, 7.68, -11.8);
    public GameObject cam1;
    public GameObject cam2;
    public GameObject cam3;
    cam1.SetActive(true)


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (cam1.SetActive(true))
        {
            transform.position = player.transform.position + offset1;
        }
        if (cam2.SetActive(true))
        {
            transform.position = player.transform.position + offset2;
        }
        if (cam3.SetActive(true))
        {
            transform.position = player.transform.position + offset3;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: remove the line `cam1.SetActive(true)` under `public GameObject cam3;`. Its missing a semicolon and it must be placed in a function scope anyway, not in class declaration scope.

Second: this statement (and the other two) `if (cam1.SetActive(true))` cant work because `SetActive` does not return a `bool` value. You probably wanted `if (cam1.activeSelf)`.

You may spend some time improving your knowledge [C# coding basics in Unity](https://unity.com/how-to/learning-c-sharp-unity-beginners)